# AutoCompleteField text filtering in Blackberry

Tags: blackberry, autocomplete, filtering

I have used `AutoCompleteField` in blackberry and filtering the text using `BasicFilteredList`. It works fine in blackberry SDK 5.0 and above. But, the search is working according to the word typed. If i have an text string as below.

> T 115 Centro Galleria Shopping Centre, Cnr Old Collier and Walters Road Morley WA 1522

It filters the string only if i type 152 but it cant filter if i use 522. I want it should filter as per my requirements as they are present in the above search string. Please help me to fix this issue. 
Below is the code sample for creating `AutoCompleteField`

```
import net.rim.device.api.collection.util.BasicFilteredList;
import net.rim.device.api.collection.util.BasicFilteredListResult;
import net.rim.device.api.ui.UiApplication;
import net.rim.device.api.ui.component.AutoCompleteField;
import net.rim.device.api.ui.component.LabelField;
import net.rim.device.api.ui.component.ListField;
import net.rim.device.api.ui.container.MainScreen;
import net.rim.device.api.ui.text.TextFilter;
import net.rim.device.api.util.CharacterUtilities;

public class AutoCompleteFieldApp extends UiApplication {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        AutoCompleteFieldApp app = new AutoCompleteFieldApp();
        app.enterEventDispatcher();
    }

    AutoCompleteFieldApp() {
        pushScreen(new HomeScreen());
    }
}

class HomeScreen extends MainScreen {
    LabelField selectedText;

    public HomeScreen() {
        setTitle("Autocomplete Text Field Demo");

         selectedText = new LabelField();

        BasicFilteredList filterList = new BasicFilteredList();
        String[] address = { "T 115 Centro Galleria Shopping Centre, Cnr Old Collier and Walters Road Morley WA 1522", 
                "1423 SEAVIEW POINT POINT COOK VIC 2674",
                "Lot 1498 Yarraman Road Wyndham Vale VIC 3795", 
                "Lot 3506 Witchmount Close Hillside VIC 4055",
                "6 Paas Place Williamstown VIC 4233", 
                "Lot 99 14 James Close Sunbury VIC 4502", 
                "1 Charlotte Street Clayton South VIC 4779" };

        filterList.addDataSet(1, address, "address", BasicFilteredList.COMPARISON_IGNORE_CASE);
        AutoCompleteField autoCompleteField = new AutoCompleteField(filterList){
            public void onSelect(Object selection, int SELECT_TRACKWHEEL_CLICK) {
                 ListField _list = getListField();
                 if (_list.getSelectedIndex() > -1) {
                     if(selectedText!=null){
                         BasicFilteredListResult result = (BasicFilteredListResult) selection;
                         selectedText.setText(result._object.toString());
                     }
                 }
             }
        };
        add(autoCompleteField);

        AutoCompleteField autoCompleteField2 = new AutoCompleteField(filterList){
            public void onSelect(Object selection, int SELECT_TRACKWHEEL_CLICK) {
                 ListField _list = getListField();
                 if (_list.getSelectedIndex() > -1) {
                     if(selectedText!=null){
                         BasicFilteredListResult result = (BasicFilteredListResult) selection;
                         selectedText.setText(result._object.toString()); 
                     }
                 }
             }
        };

        TextFilter filter = new TextFilter() {          
            public char convert(char c, int status) {
                if (!validate(c))
                    return 0;
                return c;
            }
            public boolean validate(char c) {
                return CharacterUtilities.isDigit(c);
            }
        };

        autoCompleteField2.getEditField().setFilter(filter);
        add(autoCompleteField2);
        add(selectedText);
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't try this, but I'm assuming this should work. First override `getMatchedKeywords` in your `BasicFilteredList`. You should return keywords that will trigger matching. So for your case **"1522"** you should return **{"1522", "522", "22", "2"}**. The object from `BasicFilteredListResult` should be your **"1522"**. As you see if you have several words in searchable sentence it going to be more painful to generate all these substrings. But this is limitations of the API I think.

Probably there is another solution.

Comment: As my search string is huge, more then 4000+ sentences.. so the approach wont work this case.